# copy_from_user fails, but after sometime succeed

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, redhat, kernel-module

I have this code at the Linux kernel (Red hat 8.0), I get the buf from the user and should encrypt it, and save it to my own buffer.
The problem is that it seems that the copy from user fails (return count), but after unknown runs suddenly it's OK. after it's OK, it stays like this until the restart.
Can anyone explain to me this strange situation?
The rest of the function, does something else so I didn't include it here.
The `aux_arr` is temporary and I'll copy it's data to a global array that I have.

```
ssize_t my_write_e(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {

    int byte_count = 0;
    char aux_arr[SIZE];
    up(&(encrypt.sem));
    if (encrypt.tail <= encrypt.head) {
        if (count > SIZE - encrypt.counter) {
            count = encrypt.head - encrypt.tail - 1;        }
        byte_count = copy_from_user((char*)aux_arr,(char*) buf, count);
        printk("the encryptor counter is %d\n",encrypt.counter);
        if (!(encrypt.counter)) {
            encryptor(aux_arr, ((encrypt.arr) + encrypt.tail), count
                    - byte_count, ((data) (filp->private_data))->key, ENCRYPT);
            encrypt.tail = encrypt.tail + (((count - byte_count) / 8) * 8) - 1;
        } else {
            encryptor(aux_arr, ((encrypt.arr) + encrypt.tail + 1), count
                    - byte_count, ((data) (filp->private_data))->key, ENCRYPT);
            encrypt.tail = encrypt.tail + (((count - byte_count) / 8) * 8);
        }
        encrypt.counter = encrypt.counter + (((count - byte_count) / 8) * 8);
        down(&(encrypt.sem));
        if ((count - byte_count) / 8 > 0) {
            wake_up_all(&(encrypt.r_queue));
        }
        encrypt.w_counter--;
        return (((count - byte_count) / 8) * 8);
    }
```

Comment: How does it fail?  What does it return when it is failing?  How large is SIZE?  How are the members of encrypt initialized?

Comment: this calculation is performed many times: '(((count - byte_count) / 8) * 8)' 1) it would be MUCH faster to use >>3 and << 3   2) it would be much faster to only calculate it once, into a local variable and reference that variable.

Comment: if encrypt.head == encrypt.tail, then this calculation: 'count = encrypt.head - encrypt.tail - 1;' will result in a negative number (actually a very large size_t number)

Comment: @Peter, It just fails. I try sent it a string (char*) of 8 bytes, and the copy_from_user return 8 to byte_count. SIZE is 4Kb, and the max size of buf is 4Kb as well. So i think that it's not a size problem. head and tail of the encrypt are initialized.

Comment: @user3629249 they are pointers to circular buffer. Why do you think that the calculate is wrong? And you right about the quicker program, using >> << but it's not important at this module. At the end i'll store it to local variable, but still, can it cause to this kind of behavior?
By the way, i did *8/8 in order to make sure that the number of bytes divided by 8, using >> and << can make it work too?

Comment: how are the fields of the encrypt structure set?  what are typical values when the function fails?  What are the typical values when the function succeeds?  what is the source of the parameters buf and count?

Comment: without using something like 'volatile' the /8*8 sequence will probably be optimized away by the compiler

Comment: is the code trying to round up or round down the value when it performs the /8*8 calculation?  Currently it is rounding down.  To me, that means up to 7 bytes are lost.  what is so important about the rounding?

Comment: in a circular buffer, the head pointer can be less than the tail pointer. The calculation needs to be expanded to check for this condition (I.E. when the head pointer has wrapped around the end of the buffer but the tail pointer has not yet wrapped and handle this scenario appropriately

Comment: @user3629249 I know that the head pointer can be less that the tail, I have an else condition to handle it. I just didn't include it.
Which function fails? Copy or the write? buf and count are sent to the function from the user, and the encrypt struct set is defined as follow:

`typedef struct buffer_t {
   char arr[SIZE];
   int head;
   int tail;
   int r_counter;
   int w_counter;
   int counter;
   wait_queue_head_t r_queue;
   wait_queue_head_t w_queue;
   struct semaphore sem;
} buffer;
buffer encrypt;`

Comment: @user3629249 I can't chat with you, can you chat with me please? or VIA mail?
And it's OK to round it down, i should do it at this way...

Comment: We will stay here, due to lack of @dkznhr reputation level.

Comment: The calculation that updates the tail needs to take into account the buffer end wrapping so the calculation should be: 'encrypt.tail += ( ( (count - byte_count) >> 3 ) << 3); encrypt.tail = encrypt.tail%SIZE;'

Comment: OK, i see what you meant, but still, after the init, with 8 bytes, copy_from_user still fails...

Comment: The code seems to need a re-design.  A re-design that takes into account the buffer wrap scenario and includes appropriate comments.  With out those appropriate comments, I/we have a difficult time reverse engineering the code to determine exactly what the code is expected to perform.

Comment: are you saying that the function: copy_from_user() is returning 8?  (copy_from_user returns the number of bytes NOT copied)

Comment: I know that, and my question is- why is it so?
It does not copy any data and I don't know why....

Comment: this is the prototype for copy_from_user()  "unsigned long copy_from_user (void * to, const void __user * from, unsigned long n);"  The code does not follow that prototype in the returned value type and in the 'from' parameter type and in the 'n' parameter type.

Comment: As far as I know int,long and unsigned long are all 4 bytes, so what is the different? Can it cause to this? I'll try to use the unsigned and cast the aux_arr to void*

**edit**
even with the cast and unsigned, still not working

Comment: 1.) Where buf is coming from? 2.) print buf pointer and post here

Comment: Thank you all, the problem was at another place at the code....